# OptaPlanner: Performance benefits of reusing the same constraint stream in multiple different constraints?

Tags: constraints, optaplanner

Right now my `ConstraintProvider` is structured as follows:

```
public class SchedulingConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory cf) {
        return new Constraint[] {
            teacherBreakConstraint(cf),
            teacherConflictConstraint(cf)
        };
    }

    // Simply for code reuse. Method called from two places.
    UniConstraintStream<Lecture> scheduledLecturesWithTeachers(ConstraintFactory cf) {
        return cf.forEach(Lecture.class)
                .filter(Lecture::isScheduled)
                .filter(Lecture::hasTeacher);
    }

    private Constraint teacherBreakConstraint(ConstraintFactory cf) {
        return scheduledLecturesWithTeachers(cf)          // <---- called here...
                .join(scheduledLecturesWithTeachers(cf),
                        Joiners.equal(Lectures::getTeacher),
                        ...some filtering)
                ...
                .penalize(ONE_HARD)
                .asConstraint("teacher-break");
    }

    private Constraint teacherConflictConstraint(ConstraintFactory cf) {
        return scheduledLecturesWithTeachers(cf)          // <---- ...and here
                .join(scheduledLecturesWithTeachers(cf),
                        Joiners.equal(Lectures::getTeacher),
                        ... some other filtering)
                ...
                .penalize(ONE_HARD)
                .asConstraint("teacher-conflict");
    }
}
```

Would it improve OptaPlanners performance if I restructured my code so that the `scheduledLecturesWithTeachers` constraint stream was created once and **shared between the two constraints**?

```
@Override
public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory cf) {
    
    // Create this common part ONCE, then reuse the same object in both constraints...
    UniConstraintStream<Lecture> scheduledLecturesWithTeachers = scheduledLecturesWithTeachers(cf);

    return new Constraint[] {
        teacherBreakConstraint(scheduledLecturesWithTeachers, cf),
        teacherConflictConstraint(scheduledLecturesWithTeachers, cf)
    };
}

UniConstraintStream<Lecture> scheduledLecturesWithTeachers(ConstraintFactory cf) {
    return cf.forEach(Lecture.class)
            .filter(Lecture::isScheduled)
            .filter(Lecture::hasTeacher);
}

private Constraint teacherBreakConstraint(UniConstraintStream<Lecture> scheduledLecturesWithTeachers, ConstraintFactory cf) {
    return scheduledLecturesWithTeachers          // <---- used here...
            .join(scheduledLecturesWithTeachers(cf),
                    Joiners.equal(Lectures::getTeacher),
                    ...some filtering)
            ...
            .penalize(ONE_HARD)
            .asConstraint("teacher-break");
}

private Constraint teacherConflictConstraint(UniConstraintStream<Lecture> scheduledLecturesWithTeachers, ConstraintFactory cf) {
    return scheduledLecturesWithTeachers            // <---- ...and here
            .join(scheduledLecturesWithTeachers(cf),
                    Joiners.equal(Lectures::getTeacher),
                    ... some other filtering)
            ...
            .penalize(ONE_HARD)
            .asConstraint("teacher-conflict");
}
```

Taking this one step further, would it be useful to even reuse it twice in the same constraint?

```
private Constraint teacherConflictConstraint(UniConstraintStream<Lecture> scheduledLecturesWithTeachers, ConstraintFactory cf) {
    return scheduledLecturesWithTeachers          // <---- reused object
            .join(scheduledLecturesWithTeachers,  // <---- reused again in same constraint
                    Joiners.equal(Lectures::getTeacher),
                    ... some other filtering)
            ...
            .penalize(ONE_HARD)
            .asConstraint("teacher-conflict");
}
```

---

Update: The very last approach of reusing constraint streams multiple times in a single constraint seems problematic. I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.LambdaConstraint.initBetaIndex(LambdaConstraint.java:102)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.LambdaConstraint.initIndexes(LambdaConstraint.java:92)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.LambdaConstraint.<init>(LambdaConstraint.java:72)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.KiePackagesBuilder.createSingleConstraint(KiePackagesBuilder.java:1190)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.KiePackagesBuilder.createConstraint(KiePackagesBuilder.java:1169)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.KiePackagesBuilder.addConstraintsToPattern(KiePackagesBuilder.java:1162)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.KiePackagesBuilder.addConstraintsToPattern(KiePackagesBuilder.java:1157)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.KiePackagesBuilder.buildPattern(KiePackagesBuilder.java:808)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.KiePackagesBuilder.conditionToElement(KiePackagesBuilder.java:485)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.KiePackagesBuilder.addSubConditions(KiePackagesBuilder.java:723)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.KiePackagesBuilder.populateLHS(KiePackagesBuilder.java:448)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.KiePackagesBuilder.compileRule(KiePackagesBuilder.java:251)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.KiePackagesBuilder.build(KiePackagesBuilder.java:222)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.KieBaseBuilder.createKieBaseFromModel(KieBaseBuilder.java:84)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.KieBaseBuilder.createKieBaseFromModel(KieBaseBuilder.java:64)
    at org.optaplanner.constraint.streams.drools.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.buildKieBaseFromModel(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.java:94)
    at org.optaplanner.constraint.streams.drools.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.buildKieBase(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.java:85)
    at org.optaplanner.constraint.streams.drools.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.<init>(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.java:52)
    at org.optaplanner.constraint.streams.drools.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactoryService.buildScoreDirectorFactory(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactoryService.java:75)
    at org.optaplanner.constraint.streams.drools.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactoryService.lambda$buildScoreDirectorFactory$0(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactoryService.java:54)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.decideMultipleScoreDirectorFactories(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:147)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:40)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(DefaultSolverFactory.java:165)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.<init>(DefaultSolverFactory.java:71)
    at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverFactory.createFromXmlFile(SolverFactory.java:72)
    at .......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. What you are trying to do is called "node sharing", and it is a proven performance optimization technique.

In the case of `DROOLS`, the default implementation of Constraint Streams, node sharing is unlikely to bring any performance improvements. Drools itself does support node sharing, but our CS implementation on top makes some abstractions that often prevent Drools node sharing.

In the case of `BAVET`, the alternative implementation of Constraint Streams, this most certainly does bring performance benefits. Every stream instance you reuse only gets executed once, no matter how many times you reuse it.

In general, we discourage this approach, because it makes the code read worse and harder to understand. That said, if ultimate performance is the goal, then node sharing is the way to get there.

Comment: I suspect until Java supports detecting that 2 predicates are equal, in a reliable manner, that automatic node sharing (so the user can keep pretty code) there won't be much progress in this.

Comment: Indeed, automatic node sharing is out of the question. But this manual node sharing already works, and it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey and Lukáš. Awesome answers, as always.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický turns out I get an exception when reusing a constraint stream in a join, as demonstrated in the very last snippet in the question. Is this expected, or should I file a bug?

Comment: I see you're using `DROOLS` - even though it certainly is a bug, node sharing is unlikely to bring any benefits there. Feel free to file the bug, but even if/when it is fixed, I bet you will not see performance improvements. If such a bug showed up in `BAVET`, that would be more serious, because there node sharing actually makes sense.

Comment: Aha, I see. Switching to Bavet avoids the exception. Was planning on switching to Bavet regardless, so all good :-) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, **node sharing** should make them result into the same execution node network.

In practice, it depends.

For Drools CS, I am not sure.

For Bavet CS, node sharing currently only works if 2 streams are equal. 2 streams are equal if they do the same operation and all their input streams are equal too. Its recursive basically.

But in Java, it's hard to tell if 2 Predicates are the same if they're not the same instance. Drools does some black magic to detect that. Bavet deliberately doesn't. So most of the time, Bavet won't be able to see that 2 filter streams (or any streams build upon a filter stream) are the same.

---

That being said: I suspect that in most cases, rewriting the code like you've shown above counts as *premature optimization*. I wouldn't do it, but you're allowed to do it. Use optaplanner-benchmark to determine if it's worth the more difficult to read impact.

Comment: "in Java, it's hard to tell if 2 Predicates are the same" - yep. That's why I figured it might enable some optimization if they were the same object...